# What does native_write_msr in kernel do?

Tags: kernel, perf

I have a python script that is sometimes slow at the beginning. I ran `perf top` on it the other day and all I could see was:

```
   PerfTop:       2 irqs/sec  kernel:100.0%  exact:  0.0% [4000Hz cycles],  (target_pid: 1234)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

   100.00%  [kernel]       [k] native_write_msr
```

Googling the function name didn't help me much.

Comment: MSR writes are how the kernel programs HW perf counters.  That seems odd; I wonder if a restrictive setting for `/proc/sys/kernel/perf_event_paranoid` could explain that.  (`0` allows most useful stuff on a dev machine.)  `kernel.yama.ptrace_scope = 0` might also be relevant?  What exact command did you type, and what kind of system are you on?  Does `perf stat` work normally, showing counts for instructions and cycles?

Answer (score 2):

`native_write_msr` is x86/x86_64 specific kernel function which allows kernel code to do MSR writes: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.8/source/arch/x86/include/asm/msr.h#L118

> ```
> static inline void native_write_msr(unsigned int msr,
>                       unsigned low, unsigned high)
> {
>   asm volatile("1: wrmsr\n"
>            "2:\n"
>            : : "c" (msr), "a"(low), "d" (high) : "memory");
>   if (msr_tracepoint_active(__tracepoint_write_msr))
>       do_trace_write_msr(msr, ((u64)high << 32 | low), 0);
> }
> ```

If you want to get actual MSR indexes and values you may try to activate msr tracing with https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/trace/events-msr.txt or https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.17/trace/events-msr.html instructions.

`native_write_msr` is internal implementation of kernel's `wrmsr` and `wrmsl` functions which have many possible invocations: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.8/ident/wrmsr and https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.8/ident/wrmsrl and some of them, as Peter says in comment are for programming performance counters (from `arch/x86/events` directory).

For profiling of short scripts don't use `perf top` tool (it is for long-running processes and whole system profiling), but try `perf record python3 ./your-script.py` to record profile into `perf.data` file and `perf report` or `perf report > report.txt` to decode `perf.data` file. This is very short script so I changed sample frequency to higher value, and also I did not profile kernel (`:u` suffix)

```
echo 2 | sudo tee  /proc/sys/kernel/perf_event_paranoid
$ perf record -e cycles:u -F 20000 python3 -c 'print(1)' 
1
[ perf record: Woken up 1 times to write data ]
```

`perf report` will show you statistics, but it will miss some symbols showing only hex addresses

```
$ perf report            # interactive TUI
$ perf report|head -n 20|tail
#
     9.75%  python3  python3.6          [.] _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault
     2.77%  python3  python3.6          [.] 0x000000000049b284
     1.95%  python3  libc-2.27.so       [.] __strlen_avx2
     1.86%  python3  python3.6          [.] PyObject_GetAttr
     1.80%  python3  python3.6          [.] PyDict_SetDefault
     1.61%  python3  python3.6          [.] PyUnicode_New
     1.55%  python3  libc-2.27.so       [.] _int_malloc
     1.52%  python3  python3.6          [.] _PyDict_LoadGlobal
     1.41%  python3  python3.6          [.] _PyObject_GenericSetAttrWithDict
```

`perf script` will give you timeline of code executed, listing every sample from the `perf record` (With `-F 20000` samples are taken at around 20 kHz).