# Why does `native_write_msr` dominate my profiling result?

Tags: linux-kernel, x86, profiling, perf

I have a program that runs on a multi-thread framework with Linux kernel 4.18 and Intel CPU. I ran `perf record -p pid -g -e cycles:u --call-graph lbr -F 99 -- sleep 20` to collect stack trace and generate flame graph.

[image]

My program was running under a low workload, so the time spent on `futex_wait` is expected. But the top of the stack is a kernel function `native_write_msr`. According to [What does native_write_msr in kernel do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60291553/what-does-native-write-msr-in-kernel-do) and https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.18/source/arch/x86/include/asm/msr.h#L103, this function is used for performance counters. I have disabled the tracepoint in `native_write_msr`.

And  `pidstat -p pid 1` told me that the system CPU usage is quite low.

```sh
05:44:34 PM   UID       PID    %usr %system  %guest    %CPU   CPU  Command
05:44:35 PM  1001     67441   60.00    4.00    0.00   64.00    11  my_profram
05:44:36 PM  1001     67441   58.00    7.00    0.00   65.00    11  my_profram
05:44:37 PM  1001     67441   61.00    3.00    0.00   64.00    11  my_profram
```

My questions are

1. Why does `native_write_msr` appear so many times in the stack traces (as a result, it occupies a large space in the flame graph for about 80%). Is it a block operation, or it realeases the CPU when called?
2. Why is the system CPU usage relatively low against the frame graph? According to the graph, 80% of the CPU time should belong to `%system` instead of `%usr`.

Any help is appreciated. If I miss any useful infomation, please comment.

Thank you very much!

Comment: When you say "stack space", you don't mean space in bytes, do you?  Anyway, another thing `wrmsr` is needed for is updating the FS base address for thread-local storage  (on CPUs without the `wrfsbase` instruction, or kernels not new enough to use it, like probably yours).  Probably on context-switch and/or process startup.

Comment: @PeterCordes, Thank you for your reply, I just updated my question. I still confused about question 2, the frame graph and the CPU time seem to contradict each other, how did it happen?

Comment: I upvoted your question after your edit clarified it; hopefully someone knows the answer because I don't.

Comment: @AmorFati any luck? I am experiencing the same behaviour on a multi-threaded applciation.

Comment: I'm also experiencing this and am at a loss.

Answer (score 1):

From the flamegraph, you could find that `native_write_msr` function is called by the function `schedule`. When a running process is removed from one core (because it's migrated to another core or stopped by the scheduler to run another process), the scheduler need to dump the process's perf data and clean its perf configurations, so we don't mess up perf data of different processes. The scheduler may need to write to msr in this step, thus calling `native_write_msr`. So `native_write_msr` are called for so many times because scheduling or core migrations happens too frequently.

Comment: Interesting... is the amount of space on the perf graph indicative that `native_write_msr` is actually using that much CPU, or is it just waiting in there? It tends to always appear under stuff like `futex_wait` so I suspect it's just waiting and not really using CPU... but I'm confused why the wait occurs in `native_write_msr` itself as opposed to something higher in the call stack if so.

Comment: I think the whole story of the flamegraph is like this: the process calls `pthread_cond_wait`, and `libc` internally issues a futex syscall. OS thus marks the process as blocked and decides to schedule another process. During this process's wait on a condition variable, another process runs in the core and has its own call stack (when no runnable task, the scheduler picks a special `idle()` task). So I think if perf captures a call stack, the top function of the call stack is currently using CPU.